# Call 'app.get()' from browser to download file

Tags: node.js

I have this code on my server.js:

```
app.get('/download', function (req, res) {
    var file = __dirname + "/upload_folder/file.png";
    res.download(file);
})
```

But how do i call this function from the client?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your your app server is running and listening on `http://localhost:3000`. To exercise that route, you would perform a a GET request on this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/download
```

Comment: Thanks! And how to i specify where the file is saved on the client?

Comment: You can use the [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module, assuming the client is also written in node.js. Otherwise, it totally depends on the language and framework that you are writing your client in.

Comment: I only use `socket.io` in my client code to react on the data the server sends. So i guess it is written in node.js? But how can i integrade node.js in my .html file? Just with `<script></script`? How would you do it?